# Text revision comparison StackOverflow-style for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, text-comparison

I'd like to show revisions of text, and I love how StackOverflow does it (e.g. see below). Is there an open source .NET code that can receive two texts and output such a result? If you know of a paid solution that may also be relevant, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may checkout the [following javascript library](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) by John Resig.